# Vscode authorisation taking long time

Tags: vs-code, authorization

In vscode I was unable to authorise a org even I set Java path and salesforce cli path as well but still taking long time and tried plug-in as well can anyone help me to authorise an org

Comment: how long does it take to launch your browser from CLI?